# Class has two type paramters both have a upper bound of string and number: Java

Tags: java, generics, extends

> Write the header for a generic class named MyType. The class should
>   have two type parameters. The first type parameter’s upper bound
>   should be the Number class. The second type parameter’s upper bound
>   should be the String class.

Would look something like this correct?

```
public class MyType<T extends Number> {}
```

How would I go about getting the second type parameter as a upper bound? Could I just do extends Number extends String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you declare it this way

```
 public class TestThis <T extends Number, X extends String> {}
```

thou **x extends String** works, Remember that String is a final class and you cant extend it.
Eclipse gave me this warning :

**The type parameter X should not be bounded by the final type String. Final types cannot be further extended**

Answer (score 1):

You misread the question: it's asking you to give the class two type parameters, each with a bound, not one type parameter with two bounds.

For example this class has two type parameters `T` and `U`:

```
public class MyType<T, U> { }
```

I'll leave it up to <strike>you</strike> the other answers to add the bounds.

---

**Edit:** note that if you do want multiple upper bounds on single type parameter, you use `&` to delimit them:

```
<T extends B1 & B2 & B3>
```

But since Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, additional upper bounds can only be interfaces. Here, `B1` can be a class or interface while `B2` and `B3` must be interfaces (reference: [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)).

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about getting the second type parameter as a upper bound? Could I just do extends Number extends String?

You can add the second parameter separated by a `,` like:

```
public class MyType<T extends Number, S extends String> {
}
```

**Though it looks weird since String is a final class, but you can still extend it for upper bound.**

declaration would look like:

```
MyType<Long,String> myType = new MyType<Long, String>();
```

Comment: How is `S extends String` different from simply `String` in this case?

Comment: It isn't. Technically even I would prefer `String` instead of `S extends String`

Answer (score 1):

If `A` has an *upper bound* of `B`, it means `A extends B`. Therefore, your declaration should look like this:

```
public class MyType<T extends Number, U extends String> {
    ...
}
```

You are asked to *have two type parameters* (not just one as you currently have), hence the `T` and `U` above. **But I should note:** [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is `final` and hence no type `U` can be an extension of `String` (although `U` can still be `String`).